# How should I define an alias for showing changes between upstream and local branch?

Tags: git, alias, git-log

Between those 2 aliases, I'm wondering which one's the best?

```
lc = "!git log origin/$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD).."
out = log @{u}..
```

I'm no Git expert, and by best, I mean the one which leads me to less errors; so which one is more generic, will work best with branches, etc.?

Or are they fully isomorphic?

Comment: @Jubobs, thanks for improving my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, your two aliases are meant to print a log of all commits between

- the tip of the upstream (if any) of the current branch (if any) and
- the tip of the current branch (if any).

In this respect, your two aliases are not equivalent commands. In fact, the second alias,

```
out = log @{u}..
```

is preferable to the first,

```
lc = "!git log origin/$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD).."
```

Why? Because, since the remote doesn't have to be called `origin` (but could be called `github`, `bitbucket`, `planetmars`, etc.), hardcoding `origin` in the first alias is a bad idea.